# Type of method Passed to ThreadStart Delegate using fxcop dll

Tags: fxcop

I am implementing a custom rule dll for FXcop. The rule goes as follows : "One should not use static fields inside a multithreaded method without synchronization" . For this i need to  get the type of method on which the thread is spawned. i.e. Which method is being passed as a argument to threadstart delegate. **Is there any way by which we can acheive the same using FxCopSdk.dll**  ?
Any help would be Appreciated.

With Regards,
Sriharsha